# Oembed is not clickable

Tags: block-editor, oembed

I am pasting an article from the New York Times into standard WordPress Gutenberg editor, which automatically attempts to use Oembed to fetch it. It succeeds, but the result is not clickable; it's just an image, no title, and no excerpt. You can right-click and get to the URL, however.

Checking the errors in console results in:

> Blocked opening 'https://www.nytimes.com/2016/07/20/health/ivf-breast-cancer-risk.html?ref=oembed' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.

I have tried this same URL on a few different sites to rule out the theme being an issue, and also deactivated all plugins to be sure they are not interfering either. Would this be something configured on NYT's end, or something I am doing incorrectly?